# define ROS_MASTER_URI with an ipv6 address

Tags: ros, ros-comm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I would like to know if there's a way to define ROS_MASTER_URI with an ipv6 address to use ros on multiple machines.

To be a bit more clear, I have two machines connected via ethernet, and which are able to ssh to one another with ipv6 addresses, using "ssh -6 < address >%eth0"

So, is there a similar way to make ros understand ipv6 adresses concerning ROS_MASTER_URI?

ps: I've already tried "http://< address >:11311" and "http://< address >%eth0:11311" which don't work and return "invalid master URI".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207485/define-ros_master_uri-with-an-ipv6-address/) by [Matthieu Muschinowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/22189/matthieu-muschinowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has been some work on adding IPv6 support to `ros_comm` in the past (see [wiki/ros_comm6](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_comm6) and [IPv6 Support for ROS Nodes](http://www.ros.org/news/2012/06/ipv6-support-for-ros-nodes.html) on ROS news fi), but afaik there is currently no support for IPv6 in any mainline ROS distribution.

I also believe that there are no efforts underway or planned at the moment to add IPv6 support to ROS (1.0).

However, I think that support for IPv6 might be something ROS 2.0 gets 'for free', depending on the DDS vendor chosen. Some vendors already have had support since around 2007 ([RTI Incorporates IPv6 Transport to ..](https://www.rti.com/company/news/ipv6.html)). I expect that the relevant ROS tooling / infrastructure bits will also need support, but at least the DDS middleware should be prepared for it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matthieu Muschinowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/22189/matthieu-muschinowski/) on 2015-04-21**:
Hum ok... I'll work with a static IP then, thanks for the heads up anyway!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IPv6 support got merged into ROS a while ago: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/7

I guess that you still have to activate it by setting the `ROS_IPV6` to `on`.

The easiest way to do that is to simply run:

```
export ROS_IPV6=on
```

---

Originally posted by [schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2001/schneider/) with karma: 11 on 2016-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1